# Why is GCC std::atomic increment generating inefficient non-atomic assembly?

Tags: gcc, c++11, atomic

I've been using gcc's Intel-compatible builtins (like `__sync_fetch_and_add`) for quite some time, using my own `atomic` template. The "`__sync`" functions are now officially considered "legacy".

C++11 supports `std::atomic<>` and its descendants, so it seems reasonable to use that instead, since it makes my code standard compliant, and the compiler will produce the best code either way, in a platform independent manner, that is almost too good to be true.
Incidentally, I'd only have to text-replace `atomic` with `std::atomic`, too. There's a lot in `std::atomic` (re: memory models) that I don't really need, but default parameters take care of that.

Now for the bad news. As it turns out, the generated code is, from what I can tell, ... utter crap, and not even atomic at all. Even a minimum example that increments a single atomic variable and outputs it has no fewer than 5 non-inlined function calls to `___atomic_flag_for_address`, `___atomic_flag_wait_explicit`, and `__atomic_flag_clear_explicit` (fully optimized), and on the other hand, there is not a single atomic instruction in the generated executable.

What gives? There is of course always the possibility of a compiler bug, but with the huge number of reviewers and users, such rather drastic things are generally unlikely to go unnoticed. Which means, this is probably not a bug, but intended behaviour.

What is the "rationale" behind so many function calls, and how is atomicity implemented *without* atomicity?

As-simple-as-it-can-get example:

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic_int a(5);
    ++a;
    __builtin_printf("%d", (int)a);
    return 0;
}
```

produces the following `.s`:

```
movl    $5, 28(%esp)     #, a._M_i
movl    %eax, (%esp)     # tmp64,
call    ___atomic_flag_for_address   #
movl    $5, 4(%esp)  #,
movl    %eax, %ebx   #, __g
movl    %eax, (%esp)     # __g,
call    ___atomic_flag_wait_explicit     #
movl    %ebx, (%esp)     # __g,
addl    $1, 28(%esp)     #, MEM[(__i_type *)&a]
movl    $5, 4(%esp)  #,
call    _atomic_flag_clear_explicit  #
movl    %ebx, (%esp)     # __g,
movl    $5, 4(%esp)  #,
call    ___atomic_flag_wait_explicit     #
movl    28(%esp), %esi   # MEM[(const __i_type *)&a], __r
movl    %ebx, (%esp)     # __g,
movl    $5, 4(%esp)  #,
call    _atomic_flag_clear_explicit  #
movl    $LC0, (%esp)     #,
movl    %esi, 4(%esp)    # __r,
call    _printf  #
(...)
.def    ___atomic_flag_for_address; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    ___atomic_flag_wait_explicit;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _atomic_flag_clear_explicit;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

... and the mentioned functions look e.g. like this in `objdump`:

```
004013c4 <__atomic_flag_for_address>:
mov    0x4(%esp),%edx
mov    %edx,%ecx
shr    $0x2,%ecx
mov    %edx,%eax
shl    $0x4,%eax
add    %ecx,%eax
add    %edx,%eax
mov    %eax,%ecx
shr    $0x7,%ecx
mov    %eax,%edx
shl    $0x5,%edx
add    %ecx,%edx
add    %edx,%eax
mov    %eax,%edx
shr    $0x11,%edx
add    %edx,%eax
and    $0xf,%eax
add    $0x405020,%eax
ret
```

The others are somewhat simpler, but I don't find a single instruction that would really be atomic (other than some spurious `xchg` which *are* atomic on X86, but these seem to be rather NOP/padding, since it's `xchg   %ax,%ax` following `ret`).

I'm absolutely not sure what such a rather complicated function is needed for, and how it's meant to make anything atomic.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Can you show a small program that results in such poor code? I'm running a 4.7 snapshot from last month and it seems to produce decent code, with `lock` instructions in it.

Comment: The memory model that you "don't need" comes to mind as a possible culprit. What does your code look like? Also what do you mean with the last sentence: "How is atomicity implemented without atomicity"?

Comment: By "memory models", do you mean "memory orderings"?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Using gcc 4.6.1, `__sync_fetch_and_add` produces `LOCK XADD` or `LOCK INC` if you don't consume the output (just as expected), whereas something like `std::atomic_int a(5); ++a;` produces said 5 function calls. I'll edit and provide `.s` and `objdump` output.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Re: "memory models", indeed, my bad... wrong word. I meant "memory ordering". I just need atomic increment and decrement of counters, none of the comlicated esoteric stuff.

Comment: @jalf: What I mean is, how do you increment an integer _atomically_ just by calling a function that does not contain any atomic instructions (... and, why call a complicated function when the target CPU supports that kind of thing natively).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an inadequate compiler build.

Check your `c++config.h`, it shoukld look like this, but it doesn't:

```
/* Define if builtin atomic operations for bool are supported on this host. */
#define _GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_1 1

/* Define if builtin atomic operations for short are supported on this host.
   */
#define _GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_2 1

/* Define if builtin atomic operations for int are supported on this host. */
#define _GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_4 1

/* Define if builtin atomic operations for long long are supported on this
   host. */
#define _GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_8 1
```

These macros are defined or not depending on `configure` tests, which check host machine support for `__sync_XXX` functions. These tests are in `libstdc++v3/acinclude.m4`, `AC_DEFUN([GLIBCXX_ENABLE_ATOMIC_BUILTINS] ...`.

On your installation, it's evident from the `MEM[(__i_type *)&a]` put in the assembly file by `-fverbose-asm` that the compiler uses macros from `atomic_0.h`, for example:

```
#define _ATOMIC_LOAD_(__a, __x)                        \
  ({typedef __typeof__(_ATOMIC_MEMBER_) __i_type;                          \
    __i_type* __p = &_ATOMIC_MEMBER_;                      \
    __atomic_flag_base* __g = __atomic_flag_for_address(__p);          \
    __atomic_flag_wait_explicit(__g, __x);                 \
    __i_type __r = *__p;                           \
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit(__g, __x);                      \
    __r; })
```

With a properly built compiler, with your example program, `c++ -m32 -std=c++0x -S -O2 -march=core2 -fverbose-asm` should produce something like this:

```
movl    $5, 28(%esp)    #, a.D.5442._M_i
lock addl   $1, 28(%esp)    #,
mfence
movl    28(%esp), %eax  # MEM[(const struct __atomic_base *)&a].D.5442._M_i, __ret
mfence
movl    $.LC0, (%esp)   #,
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)   # __ret,
call    printf  #
```

Comment: And guess what, editing `c++config.h` to contain those defines fixes the issue, giving me exactly the `lock addl, mfence` sequence that you posted above, which is what I wanted, too. (I'll forward the issue to my compiler builder). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There are two implementations. One that uses the `__sync` primitives and one that does not. Plus a mixture of the two that only uses some of those primitives. Which is selected depends on macros `_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_1`, `_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_2`, `_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_4` and `_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_8`.

At least the first one is needed for the mixed implementation, all are needed for the fully atomic one. It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560882/glibcxx-atomic-builtins-not-defined-in-gcc-4-4-5) that whether they are defined depends on target machine (they may not be defined for `-mi386` and should be defined for `-mi686`).

Comment: None of these are defined here although atomic insns are certainly available (I'm compiling for `-march=core2`) and work without problem using the `__sync` functions. I've tried to define these macros before including `<atomic>` just to see if that makes a difference, doesn't though. So basically you're saying this is probably a kind of "poor man's fallback implementation"? In that case, how would I enable the real one (without compiling my own gcc)?