# Strange errors in intel's tbb

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tbb, gcc4

I've build intel's tbb, and in my qt pro file I've included following line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Downloads\\libraries\\tbb40_297oss\\include"
```

but when I try to compile my project I'm getting an error:

```
c:\Downloads\libraries\tbb40_297oss\include\tbb\internal\..\tbb_exception.h:340: error: 'exception_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Is there anything else I'm supposed to do? I cannot find any .lib files anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have `_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_N` *(N = 1,2,4,8)* defined in `bits/c++config.h`

Well this was my problem. [It turned out that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560882/glibcxx-atomic-builtins-not-defined-in-gcc-4-4-5) my MingW was not installed properly because of a configuration issue.

When I was dealing with that I had spent too much time with those types of shit and it was very very late at night. I had got sick and defined those macros myself.

TBB compiles and runs without problems since that day.

Comment: @smallB: You can try to figure out, why you do not have those macros defined and how you can make MingW installed properly. When there is no hope for you go and define those macros. By the way, definitions of macros are commented out by default. Look at your bits/c++config.h